# Dynamically Swapping Material Icons with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, google-material-icons

Generally, I use static google material icons like this.

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xE85E;</i>
```

However, I want to dynamically change the material icon using a computed property with VueJS. I tried the following:

```
<i class="material-icons font-size-36-i">{{ materialIconCode }}</i>

computed: {
  materialIconCode: function () {
    return '&#xE85E'
  }
}
```

It does not work instead it displays `&# E  E` on the page with the numbers missing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/tbm75a06/

The mustache syntax interprets the data as text. Use the directive `v-html="materialIconCode"` to set the html of an element.

Comment: For any future readers, the v-html directive is susceptible to XSS and you should protect your app accordingly